# Parsing JSON array and objects Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

I am just started to study and need you help.
I am a bit confused about JSON parsing in below output...
This is my output...

```
{
    "item": [
        {
            "body": [
                {
                    "item_name": "tralala",
                    "publish_date": "2015-10-08 ",
                    "price": null,
                    "code": null,
                    "contact_name": "somename",
                    "contact_email": "somemail",
                    "contact_number": "989899833",
                    "image_format": "jpg",
                    "img_url": "uploads/",
                    "state": "",
                    "city": "",
                    "area": ""
                }
            ],
            "image": [
                {
                    "image_name": "2443"
                },
                {
                    "image_name": "2444"
                },
                {
                    "image_name": "2445"
                },
                {
                    "image_name": "2446"
                },
                {
                    "image_name": "2447"
                },
                {
                    "image_name": "2448"
                },
                {
                    "image_name": "2449"
                },
                {
                    "image_name": "2450"
                },
                {
                    "image_name": "2451"
                },
                {
                    "image_name": "2452"
                },
                {
                    "image_name": "2453"
                },
                {
                    "image_name": "2454"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Finally I have one array **item** with two objects **body** and **image**

How correctly parse the data?
For **image** object probably need to run **for** ...
What code you can suggest to transfer data into variables?
Thank you for your time...!

Comment: your json string have problem

Comment: Actually is was copied and pasted from advanced rest client, it is valid data

Comment: Your 1st JSON string is invalid, but 2nd are valid...

Comment: Just updated the post, sry for confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse above data with following method

```
 public void parseData() {
    List<String> imglist=new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray jarr = null;
    try {
        jarr = jobj.getJSONArray("item");
        JSONObject job1 = jarr.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray body_arr = job1.getJSONArray("body");
        JSONObject job2 = body_arr.getJSONObject(0);

        String item_name = job2.getString("item_name");
        //similarly other strings present in job2


        JSONArray img_arr = job1.getJSONArray("image");
        for (int i = 0; i < img_arr.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject img_ob = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
            String img_ame=img_ob.getString("image_name");
            imglist.add(img_ame);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

To tranfer json data to variable you can use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Here is your result:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Image {
 @SerializedName("image_name")
 public String imageName;
}

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Body {
 @SerializedName("item_name")
 public String itemName;
 @SerializedName("publish_date")
 public String publishDate;
 @SerializedName("price")
 public Object price;
 @SerializedName("code")
 public Object code;
 @SerializedName("contact_name")
 public String contactName;
 @SerializedName("contact_email")
 public String contactEmail;
 @SerializedName("contact_number")
 public String contactNumber;
 @SerializedName("image_format")
 public String imageFormat;
 @SerializedName("img_url")
 public String imgUrl;
 @SerializedName("state")
 public String state;
 @SerializedName("city")
 public String city;
 @SerializedName("area")
 public String area;
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

 @SerializedName("item")
 public List < Item > item = new ArrayList < Item > ();
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Item {
 @SerializedName("body")
 public List < Body > body = new ArrayList < Body > ();
 @SerializedName("image")
 public List < Image > image = new ArrayList < Image > ();
}
```

Comment: you can use AsynTask to get json string data/ or stream then use gson with data as abover